# 3D plotting of a dataset that uses K-means

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, k-means

```
X, t = make_swiss_roll(n_samples=1000, noise=0.2, random_state=42)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)                   # Number of clusters == 3
kmeans = kmeans.fit(X)                          # Fitting the input data
labels = kmeans.predict(X)                      # Getting the cluster labels
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_             # Centroid values
print("Centroids are:", centroids)              # From sci-kit learn

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = np.array(labels==0)
y = np.array(labels==1)
z = np.array(labels==2)
ax.scatter(x,y,z, marker="s"[kmeans.labels_], s=40, cmap="RdBu")
```

I am trying to Plot the clusters in 3D by colouring all labels belonging to their class, and plot the centroids using a separate symbol. I managed to get the KMeans technique working, atleast I believe I did. But I'm stuck trying to plot it in 3D. I believe there can be a simple solution I'm just not seeing it. Does anyone have any idea what I need to change in my solution to achieve this?

Comment: What is it doing that you don't want it to? Are you getting an error? Is the plot not correct?

Comment: @wundermahn yes i tried the code, the plot doesnt work

Comment: Then @OkayDataScience should include the error in the question.

Comment: @okayDataScience all is good?

Comment: @ombk Yes perfect! I was so close thx! Not sure how to give you more credit or w.e quite new to stack overflow

Comment: @OkayDataScience click on the arrow on my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_swiss_roll
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
X, t = make_swiss_roll(n_samples=1000, noise=0.2, random_state=42)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)                   # Number of clusters == 3
kmeans = kmeans.fit(X)                          # Fitting the input data
labels = kmeans.predict(X)                      # Getting the cluster labels
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_             # Centroid values
# print("Centroids are:", centroids)              # From sci-kit learn


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = np.array(labels==0)
y = np.array(labels==1)
z = np.array(labels==2)


ax.scatter(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1],centroids[:,2],c="black",s=150,label="Centers",alpha=1)
ax.scatter(X[x,0],X[x,1],X[x,2],c="blue",s=40,label="C1")
ax.scatter(X[y,0],X[y,1],X[y,2],c="yellow",s=40,label="C2")
ax.scatter(X[z,0],X[z,1],X[z,2],c="red",s=40,label="C3")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, now the clusters are black X:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_swiss_roll
X, t = make_swiss_roll(n_samples=1000, noise=0.2, random_state=42)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)                   # Number of clusters == 3
kmeans = kmeans.fit(X)                          # Fitting the input data
labels = kmeans.predict(X)                      # Getting the cluster labels
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_             # Centroid values
print("Centroids are:", centroids)              # From sci-kit learn

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = np.array(labels==0)
y = np.array(labels==1)
z = np.array(labels==2)


ax.scatter(X[x][:, 0], X[x][:, 1], X[x][:, 2], color='red')
ax.scatter(X[y][:, 0], X[y][:, 1], X[y][:, 2], color='blue')
ax.scatter(X[z][:, 0], X[z][:, 1], X[z][:, 2], color='yellow')
ax.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], centroids[:, 2],
            marker='x', s=169, linewidths=10,
            color='black', zorder=50)
```

[image]

Comment: indeed. Found the same